# http get returns lines ending with \r\n\r\n not \r\n

Tags: python, http

```
import socket

s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
s.connect(('www.sina.com.cn', 80))
s.send(b'GET / HTTP/1.1\r\nHost: www.sina.com.cn\r\nConnection: close\r\n\r\n')
buffer = []
while True:
    d = s.recv(1024)
    if d:
        buffer.append(d)
    else:
        break
data = b''.join(buffer)
s.close()
with open('d:/sina.html', 'wb') as f:
    f.write(data)
print('done!')enter code here
```

In `s.send(xxx)`, there are two `\r\n\r\n` after `close`, and it works, but if I only write one `\r\n`, then I get nothing.
Why would this happen?

Comment: Hey, how about : import requests; print(requests.get('sina.com.cn').text)

Comment: thanks, I just learned python and try to use socket

Comment: I understand, though it makes things so much harder. Especially if you don't know HTTP in details.
This would be 3 lines of code re-using the wheel.

Answer (score 4):

Because that's a requirement in the HTTP protocol; you **have** to close off headers with a double CRLF pair. This applies even if there is no request body.

Answer (score 2):

From wikipedia:

> The end of the header section is indicated by an empty field line, resulting in the transmission of two consecutive CR-LF pairs.

Quick glance at the [HTTP header fields](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_header_fields#General_format) wikipedia page should clear up the confusion.